# Hacer captura con html2canvas y guardarla en un servidor

Tags: html, ajax, canvas, servidor

Veo que con esta librería podemos conseguir imprimir la imagen resultante en alguna parte del DOM o incluso descargarla pero, ¿hay alguna manera de guardarla en un servidor?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago así

Tengo mi canvas

```
<canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="cursor: text;">Canvas not supported</canvas>
```

después con js lo ubico

```
drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas')
```

obtengo la imagen del canvas así

```
 var data = drawingCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

y en mi caso con js invoco un método post de una pagina en c# mediante ajax y le mando lo que tenga "data"

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    url: 'webservice.aspx',
    data: {'data': dat},
    success: function (data) {
        return data.d;
    }
});
```

y ya en mi código de c# recojo la variable y la tranformo en base64 y después a un archivo de imagen y la guardo en una ruta en especifico

```
string data = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["data"]) ? Request.Form["data"] : "";
    if (data != "")
    {
        Base64ToImage(data);
    }

public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    string subPath = Session["id"].ToString(); 
    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temporales/" + subPath));
    if (!exists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temporales/" + subPath));

    string base64 = base64String.Substring(base64String.IndexOf(',') + 1);
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
        String saveImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temporales/" + Session["id"] +"/");
        string diagonal = "/";
        string nombreImg = Session["IdReg"] + "_Imagen_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + ".jpg";
        bm.Save(saveImagePath + diagonal + nombreImg);



        return bm;
    }
}
```

Así es como lo hago yo, espero algo de esto te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Vaya, interesante! Por desgracia no se mucho de c#... Sabes si con php se podría? De todos modos tomo nota, es posible que me sirva. Mil gracias!

Comment: Claro que deberías poder, hasta el punto donde mando a llamar con ajax el web service es puro javaScript supongo sería lo mismo, solamente debes recoger con post en php la variable "data" y darle el tratamiento para convertirla primero en base64 y de allí a una imagen, no le muevo mucho al php si no con gusto te ayudaría a hacerlo, pero no tengo dudas que se puede hacer en base a lo que te pongo aquí